# rest_no_route on custom API endpoint wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, wp-api

I've been trying to figure this out for the last day or so to no avail.

I'm trying to create an endpoint to gather data from a set of tables. I'm trying to write it in OOP because I need to learn.

here's my class:

```
         class b2_items_rest_route extends WP_REST_Controller{
         private $wpdb;

         public function __construct(){
             global $wpdb;
             $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
         }

         public function b2_register_route(){
             $version = '1';
             $namespace = 'b2rest/v' . $version;
             $base = 'route';

             register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base,
                array(
                    array(
                        'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                        'callback'            => array($this, 'items_by_id'),
                        'permission_callback' => array($this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
                        'args'                => array(),
                    ),
                )
            );

            register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base . '/trees/(?P<id>[\d]+)',
                array(
                    array(
                        'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                        'callback'            => array($this, 'items_by_id'),
                        'permission_callback' => array($this, 'get_item_permissions_check' ),
                        'args'                => array(),
                    )
                )
            );
         }

         function items_by_id($request){
             global $wpdb;
             //$tree_id = $request->get_param('id');
             $tree = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM bb_bower__tree_configuration WHERE tree_id=47");
         }

         public function get_items_permissions_check($request){
             return true; // make endpoint available for everyone to read.
         }

     }

     $b2_items_rest_route = new b2_items_rest_route;
     add_action('rest_api_init', $b2_items_rest_route->b2_register_route);
```

the problem is that I keep getting rest_no_route in postman but when I re-write it regularly it works fine.

any direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you flush permalinks after setting up your endpoints? I noticed your `add_action` call doesn't pass a valid callable object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't valid:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', $b2_items_rest_route->b2_register_route);
```

By all rights this should generate either a warning or a fatal error

`add_action` takes a PHP callable as a second parameter, e.g.:

- `'function_name'`
- `function( $im_a_closure_yay) {}`
- `array( 'class_name', 'static_method' )`
- `array( $object, 'method' )`

Comment: Yes, turns out that was wrong, I ended up re-writing the whole class to something that made more sense